# Using Google Design Library how to hide FAB button on Scroll down?

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library, floating-action-button

Google have released Design library, I am using

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

However I cant see any code examples of how to use this library and how to animate the `FAB` bar on scroll. I guess I can listen for scroll events on the `ListView` and then animate the button myself, but is this not baked into the API (is this not the point of this support library).

Is there examples for this ?

Comment: Here's one https://guides.codepath.com/android/Floating-Action-Buttons

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to show/hide FAB on scroll Recycler view with coordinator parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41699160/how-to-show-hide-fab-on-scroll-recycler-view-with-coordinator-parent)

Answer (score 113):

If you're using `RecyclerView` and you're looking for something simple, you can try this:

```
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy){
            if (dy > 0)
                fabAddNew.hide();
            else if (dy < 0)
                fabAddNew.show();
        }
    });
```

By replacing `0` with a constant, you can adjust the sensitivity of triggering, providing smoother experience

Comment: What if your RecyclerView is in a Fragment?

Comment: What will be the difference if it is?

Comment: No access to fabAddNew in Fragment?

Comment: @T.Coutlakis `((FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById())`

Comment: What an awesome answer! simple and doesn't require any layout modification, +1 .

Comment: How it will work if you use custom Scrolling like `EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener`

Comment: It is the simplest solution and works with a simple copy paste!

Comment: It's better to add `fabAddNew.isShown()` to avoid much works on scroll.

Answer (score 47):

Making a component react to scroll events is most easily done with a custom [CoordinatorLayout.Behavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.Behavior.html), as they receive scroll events automatically when you override [onStartNestedScroll()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.Behavior.html#onStartNestedScroll(android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout,%20V,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.View,%20int)).

An example Behavior that hides and shows the FAB on scroll found in this [FABAwareScrollingViewBehavior](https://github.com/ianhanniballake/cheesesquare/blob/scroll_aware_fab/app/src/main/java/com/support/android/designlibdemo/FABAwareScrollingViewBehavior.java), built on top of [cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare):

```
public class FABAwareScrollingViewBehavior
    extends AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior {
  public FABAwareScrollingViewBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent,
      View child, View dependency) {
    return super.layoutDependsOn(parent, child, dependency) ||
            dependency instanceof FloatingActionButton;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onStartNestedScroll(
      final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, final View child,
      final View directTargetChild, final View target,
      final int nestedScrollAxes) {
    // Ensure we react to vertical scrolling
    return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL
            || super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child,
               directTargetChild, target, nestedScrollAxes);
  }

  @Override
  public void onNestedScroll(
      final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, final View child,
      final View target, final int dxConsumed, final int dyConsumed,
      final int dxUnconsumed, final int dyUnconsumed) {
    super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target,
      dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);
    if (dyConsumed > 0) {
      // User scrolled down -> hide the FAB
      List<View> dependencies = coordinatorLayout.getDependencies(child);
      for (View view : dependencies) {
        if (view instanceof FloatingActionButton) {
          ((FloatingActionButton) view).hide();
        }
      }
    } else if (dyConsumed < 0) {
      // User scrolled up -> show the FAB
      List<View> dependencies = coordinatorLayout.getDependencies(child);
      for (View view : dependencies) {
        if (view instanceof FloatingActionButton) {
          ((FloatingActionButton) view).show();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where your scrolling view would have `app:layout_behavior="com.support.android.designlibdemo.FABAwareScrollingViewBehavior"` instead of `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

However you can replace `hide()` and `show()` with any action if you want. Details on how this was done can be found in [this post](https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/haQL1mnTzaw) and the [follow up post for v22.2.1](https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/M2wPSXgGGAF) and the [follow up post for v25.1.0](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+IanLake/posts/B4aBZYaRbqy).

Note that this, like all scrolling behaviors of the Design Library, require that your view supports nested scrolling, which currently limits you to [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html), [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)  - `ListView` and `ScrollView` only work on API21+ devices.

Comment: This is the right solution. Just additional explaination: to use it give your android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton this attribute: app:layout_behavior="org.example.something.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"

Comment: There is a method ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(listView, true);

Comment: @Yaroslav - sure, `ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled()` exists, but that just does the version check for you - it is a no-op prior to API 21.

Comment: after making child hide [child.hide() ] OnNestedScroll is not calling at all,,,any idea ???

Comment: @oshurmamadov - that's a [change in behavior in v25.1.0](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230298) - I've updated the code in the answer to do it the right way now.

Answer (score 12):

If you're **NOT** using a RecycleView (that is, just regular **ScrollView**) this will do the trick:

```
mScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            if (mScrollView.getScrollY() > oldScrollYPostion) {
                fab.hide();
            } else if (mScrollView.getScrollY() < oldScrollYPostion || mScrollView.getScrollY() <= 0) {
                fab.show();
            }
            oldScrollYPostion = mScrollView.getScrollY();
        }
    });
```

Don't forget to declare:

```
private int oldScrollYPostion = 0;
```

inside you class.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a simple ScrollView solution, almost every article is about RecyclerViews

Answer (score 6):

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
app:layout_anchor="@id/recyclerList"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
```

This did the trick for me, both FAB and RecyclerView direct childs on a Coordinator.

Comment: Despite all overly mixed programmatically solution with more votes I like this way because first it's working and second it's simple.

Answer (score 4):

The @ianhanniballake solution is working fine but the methods `onStartNestedScroll()` and `onNestedScroll()` were deprecated. Here is the **updated version**:

```
public class FabAwareScrollingViewBehavior extends AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior {

    public FabAwareScrollingViewBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
        return super.layoutDependsOn(parent, child, dependency) ||
                dependency instanceof FloatingActionButton;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
                                       @NonNull View child, @NonNull View directTargetChild,
                                       @NonNull View target, int axes, int type) {
        // Ensure we react to vertical scrolling
        return axes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL ||
                super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, directTargetChild, target, axes, type);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedPreScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
                                  @NonNull View child, @NonNull View target, int dx, int dy,
                                  @NonNull int[] consumed, int type) {
        super.onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dx, dy, consumed, type);

        if (dy > 0) {
            // User scrolled down -> hide the FAB
            List<View> dependencies = coordinatorLayout.getDependencies(child);
            for (View view : dependencies) {
                if (view instanceof FloatingActionButton) {
                    ((FloatingActionButton) view).hide();
                }
            }
        } else if (dy < 0) {
            // User scrolled up -> show the FAB
            List<View> dependencies = coordinatorLayout.getDependencies(child);
            for (View view : dependencies) {
                if (view instanceof FloatingActionButton) {
                    ((FloatingActionButton) view).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also there is a very good post by @ianhanniballake on this topic: [Intercepting everything with CoordinatorLayout Behaviors](https://medium.com/google-developers/intercepting-everything-with-coordinatorlayout-behaviors-8c6adc140c26)

Comment: In which elemnt do i have to set the behaviour?

Comment: You're a life saver. None of the other behaviors worked, but yours did. Thanks so much!

Comment: tried this and the fab doesn't come up as a dependency of the layout even though it is a child of coordinator layout so calls to hide/show never happen

Answer (score 3):

```
recyclerView.setOnFlingListener(new RecyclerView.OnFlingListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(int velocityX, int velocityY) {
        if (velocityY < 0)
            mScrollCallbacks.showUI();
            //Code to hide the UI, I have  a custom one that slides down the nav  bar and the fab
        else if (velocityY > 0)
            mScrollCallbacks.hideUI();
            //Code to show the UI

        return false;
    }
});
```

This works very well

Answer (score 2):

Using CoordinatorLayout is best way. 
Hoever if you want to attach listener to ListView or RecyclerView you also can do that. 
I think is more customizable. 
Here is my example on git hub.

[Github Project: Hide FAB(material Library) with listview](https://github.com/febaisi/FABHideListView)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this on `onScrollStateChanged` instead of `onScrolled`:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
                fab.show();
            else
                fab.hide();
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was the following:

mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

```
          @Override
          public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
              if (dy>0){
                fab.hide();
              }else if (dy == 0){

                  fab.show();
              }else{
                  fab.show();
              }
          }

          @Override
          public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {

              super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
          }
      });
```

Let me know if it works for you as well.