# How to use NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

In my application I want use `NestedScrollView` into `DrawerLayout`.
And for this I write below code.
I want show FAB in **bottom of layout**, but show me below of card!
I don't want show in below of card, I want show bottom of layout!
Please see below image to understand what I mean:

[image]

My codes:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toNightDrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="end">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsLay"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="visible">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsCard"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding8"
                        ads:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                        ads:cardElevation="@dimen/size2"
                        app:contentPadding="@dimen/padding8">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsHeaderLay"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/size50">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsHeaderImage"
                                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size35"
                                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size35"
                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                    android:alpha="0.8"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_comments"
                                    android:tint="@color/darkBlueGrey" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsUserTypeText"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding10"
                                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsHeaderImage"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:textColor="@color/darkBlueGrey"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font16" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsReviewTypeText"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding10"
                                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsUserTypeText"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:textColor="@color/darkBlueGrey"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font14" />

                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsRecyclerView"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsHeaderLay"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding5" />

                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                </RelativeLayout>
                <!--EmptyList-->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_EmptyLsy"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <include layout="@layout/empty_list" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_FilterBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding15"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_filter"
                app:fabSize="normal" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Hey man try this code :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toNightDrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="end">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsLay"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="visible">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsCard"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding8"
                        ads:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                        ads:cardElevation="@dimen/size2"
                        app:contentPadding="@dimen/padding8">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsHeaderLay"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/size50">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsHeaderImage"
                                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size35"
                                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size35"
                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                    android:alpha="0.8"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_comments"
                                    android:tint="@color/darkBlueGrey" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsUserTypeText"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding10"
                                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsHeaderImage"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:textColor="@color/darkBlueGrey"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font16" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsReviewTypeText"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding10"
                                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsUserTypeText"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:textColor="@color/darkBlueGrey"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font14" />

                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsRecyclerView"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsHeaderLay"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding5" />

                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                </RelativeLayout>
                <!--EmptyList-->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_EmptyLsy"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <include layout="@layout/empty_list" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_FilterBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding15"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_filter"
            app:fabSize="normal" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

So try do that:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/toNightDrawerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:openDrawer="end">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsLay"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="visible">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsCard"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding8"
                        ads:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                        ads:cardElevation="@dimen/size2"
                        app:contentPadding="@dimen/padding8">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsHeaderLay"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/size50">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsHeaderImage"
                                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size35"
                                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size35"
                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                    android:alpha="0.8"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_comments"
                                    android:tint="@color/darkBlueGrey" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsUserTypeText"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding10"
                                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsHeaderImage"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:textColor="@color/darkBlueGrey"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font16" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsReviewTypeText"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding10"
                                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsUserTypeText"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:textColor="@color/darkBlueGrey"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font14" />

                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsRecyclerView"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsHeaderLay"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding5" />

                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                </RelativeLayout>
                <!--EmptyList-->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_EmptyLsy"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <include layout="@layout/empty_list" />

                </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

     <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/reviewSerialFrag_FilterBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding15"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_filter"
                app:fabSize="normal" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Set all contect inside a coordinator layout and fab outside the nestedscrollview .If not work ask me to send other possible way.

Comment: @Kir no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Widget.AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <include
        layout="@layout/include_layout_toolbar_scroll"/>

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


 <include layout="@layout/include_layout_content_with_nestedscroll"/>

 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_task_accept"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
     android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_accepted"
     app:layout_behavior="pass.to.FabScrollBehavior.Class"
    app:theme="@style/Widget.AppTheme.Fab"/>

< /android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> use coordinatorlayout

use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560770/hide-fab-in-nestedscrollview-when-scrolling?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: I can use into CoordinatorLayout
 , but I have problem with above codes! please help me with my above codes my friend

Comment: hey @hamid.Waezi you use CoordinatorLayout but above question with NestedScrollView . for use FAB into NestedScrollView you use my below code. i hope help you