# how to show/hide FAB on scroll Recycler view with coordinator parent

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button, recyclerview-layout

I have an activity with coordinator layout.inside activity there is a fragment with Recycler view and float button.how can I show/hide float button when Scroll Recycler view and avoid to use fab behavior?!

in activity layout:
CoordinatorLayout----->AppBarLayout---->Toolbar and FrameLayout and Bottom bar view

in fragment layout:
RelativeLayout---->Recycler view and float button

I want to implement something like Google+ home page.
how can I implement this scenario?

---

#### Temporary I used this solution for my problem:

using coordinator layout of activity by interface in my fragment and show/hide fab with fab behavior ... until I find better solution!!!

Comment: You should probably implement some kind of scroll behavior for the FAB in your project then set layout_behavior property of the FAB to the custom scroll behavior you need.  `app:layout_behavior="com.example.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"`... Tell me if you'd like a code snippet for this

Comment: even fab doesn`t exist in coordinator layout?

Comment: I understand that you have a fragment layout with the FAB.. Well I advise you to move the FAB to the Activity Layout ... Carefully position it using `layout_gravity` e.g `start|bottom` since the coordinator layout is just a frame layout on steroids

Comment: so my fab displays in all my fragments!!

Comment: In your current layout arrangement the FAB is within a FrameLayout not inside the Coordinator layout ... - You can show and hide it as you attach different fragments to the activity since it is a view

Comment: yes it is and it doesn`t work well

Comment: Any better solution? i have similar problem, but instead of hide i want to move it down.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This code works just fine:

```
 mRecycler.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    if(dy > 0){
                        mFab.hide();
                    } else{
                        mFab.show();
                    }

                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                }
            });
```

You cannot do:

```
app:layout_anchor="@id/listView"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
```

Look [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Floating-Action-Buttons):

> There is no support built-in for CoordinatorLayout to work with
>   ListView according to [this Google post](https://plus.google.com/101784949561498190574/posts/KPbsTY4NANx).

Comment: @Zahra.HY Did this solution didn't fit what you were expecting?

Answer (score 6):

I modified Leondro's method such that the FAB will hide when there's scrolling and show when the scrolling stops.

```
scrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {  
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        switch (newState) {
            case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                fab.show();
                break;
            default:
                fab.hide();
                break;
        }
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }
}; 

rv.clearOnScrollListeners();
rv.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
```

Comment: @behelit, it's not required. unless if you have other listeners already attached and want to remove them.

Answer (score 5):

You can add this property in your floating action button:

app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working solution:

```
class HideOnScrollFabBehavior(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : FloatingActionButton.Behavior() {

    // changes visibility from GONE to INVISIBLE when fab is hidden because
    // due to CoordinatorLayout.onStartNestedScroll() implementation
    // child view's (here, fab) onStartNestedScroll won't be called anymore
    // because it's visibility is GONE
    private val listener = object : FloatingActionButton.OnVisibilityChangedListener() {
        override fun onHidden(fab: FloatingActionButton?) {
            fab?.visibility = INVISIBLE
        }
    }

    override fun onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout, child: FloatingActionButton, directTargetChild: View, target: View, axes: Int, type: Int): Boolean {
        return axes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL // Ensure we react to vertical scrolling
                || super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, directTargetChild, target, axes, type)
    }

    override fun onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout, child: FloatingActionButton, target: View, dxConsumed: Int, dyConsumed: Int, dxUnconsumed: Int, dyUnconsumed: Int, type: Int, consumed: IntArray) {
        super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, type, consumed)
        if (!target.canScrollVertically(1) && dyConsumed > 0 && child.visibility == VISIBLE) {
            // hide the FAB when scroll view reached its bottom
            child.hide(listener)
        } else if (dyConsumed < 0 && child.visibility != VISIBLE) {
            // show the FAB on scroll up
            child.show()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution in Kotlin**

```
recycler_view = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)

        recycler_view.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                if(dy > 0){
                    fab.hide();
                } else{
                    fab.show();
                }
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

            }
        })
```